# Procedure which gives grants, Invalid table name error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, database-metadata, execute-immediate

I'm trying to create a procedure which gives grants to specific schema objects. Procedure seems to compile ok, but it gives an error when execution.

Something is wrong in this simple procedure but I cannot find the reason for this.

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure ch.grants_to_schema_objects(
          i_target_schema varchar2, 
          i_target_user varchar2) as
begin
 for mt in (SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || chr(39) 
              || i_target_schema || chr(39) 
              || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' TO ' || chr(39) 
              || i_target_user || chr(39)
              || ' WITH GRANT OPTION' as grnt 
          FROM ALL_TABLES 
          WHERE OWNER = i_target_schema) loop
  dbms_output.put_line(mt.grnt);
  execute immediate mt.grnt;
end loop;
end;
```

call:

```
 execute ch.grants_to_schema_objects('SR', 'CH');
```

Error:

> ```
> ORA-06512: "CH.GRANTS_TO_SCHEMA_OBJECTS", line 5
> ORA-06512: line 1
> 00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

Comment: why the chr(39)? You may not need it. You possibly may need a double quote (") to handle lower case objects, if any

Comment: What is the output you get immediately before the error (assuming you have `set serveroutput on`)? What happens when you run that manually? As Aleksej said, the quotes around the schema and user names are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CHR(39)` is breaking it. Replace it whit `CHR(34)`: it is `"` you need to separate your username, not `'`.